# How to choose a sweep range for a known and unknown device with a VNA?

Tags: rf, antenna, vna

I'm trying to determine best practices for using a VNA to measure say, an antenna.

1. Let's say I have a known antenna with a spec sheet that says it's frequency range is between x and y. Should I set up my VNA with the sweep range x and y? Is there any information to be gleaned about the antenna outside the range x and y, or is all information outside of x and y meaningless since its not to specification? What are the recommended number of data points and why?
2. Let's say I was walking down the street and found an antenna with no markings. I have no specification sheet. I hook up the antenna to my VNA. Assuming the antenna is in good working order, how do I determine my sweep range? Looking at a wide range, let's say the maximum and minumum of my VNA's capabilities, I may see peaks and valleys in several areas of my graphical analysis. How do I determine which of these peaks and valleys corresponds to the intended/manufactured bandwidth specification of the unknown antenna? What are the recommended number of data points and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With just a VNA, you're only able to check the impedance match of the antenna, not its radiation pattern, gain, or other characteristics. If you know the intended frequency range for use, there's no reason to make measurements outside that range. The number of points should be sufficient so that you don't miss a sharp resonance; with automated sweeps and data recording, why skimp?

In case 2, you wouldn't start with a VNA. You'd study the physical structure of the antenna and its size, then hypothesize its purpose and frequency range, and finally test your hypotheses by measuring with the VNA. You'll still miss important information on directivity and gain.